# Input value is not clearing based on another input field

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I can achieve the "field2" read-only if the "field1" value is null.

But In another condition "field1" having value and I entered the "field2" value, afterward, I have removed the "field1" value in that scenario I need to empty my "field2".

How to make that one possible?

```html
Field1: <input type="text " class="form-control" formControlName="degree" #degree/><br><br>


Field2: <input type="text " class="form-control" formControlName="subject" [readonly]="degree.value == ''" />
```

Comment: you could associate a change event with the fields and then call upon a function to `patchValue` to your formControl. Or better still you could use ValueChange observable on your form and then based on the values of various fields you could manipulate the field you desire to.

Comment: What is your formGroup name?

Comment: qualificationFormGroup